# python pandas min() not picking up minimum

Tags: python, pandas

I've encountered a strange problem. I'm sure there is a logical reason behind this.

I have a dataframe called alloptions that has 4 columns, minage1, minage2, minage3, and minage4, which are all float64. the number of missing values increases from minage1 to minage4.

I create a fifth column that takes the minimum of these four columns:

```
alloptions['minage']=alloptions.apply(lambda x: min([x['minage1'],x['minage2'],x['minage3'],x['minage4']]),axis=1)
```

which looked like it worked until i discovered that in row 47

```
     minage1    minage2 minage3 minage4 minage      
47     NaN      56.0    NaN      NaN     NaN
```

using .loc, I isolate that row:

```
In [10]:

 print alloptions.loc[47,:]
 print alloptions.loc[47,:].dtypes
```

I get

```
minage1   NaN
minage2    56
minage3   NaN
minage4   NaN
minage    NaN
Name: 47, dtype: float64
float64
```

so I'm confused as to why the function didn't pick up 56.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the builtin Python `min` function, which doesn't know about `nan` and treats it inconsistently:

```
>>> min(1, np.nan)
1
>>> min(np.nan, 1)
nan
```

Instead, use the `min` method from `pandas`, which knows to ignore `nan` values when computing the min.  This method takes an `axis` argument, so if your four `minageX` columns are the only columns in your DataFrame, you can just do

```
df['minage'] = df.min(axis=1)
```

In general when working with pandas data structures you should avoid using builtin Python functions like max, min, sum, and so on, and instead use the pandas versions; the builtin functions do not know anything about pandas or about vectorized operations, and may give unexpected results.

Comment: @chungkim271 you should mark this answer as accepted (the checkmark that turns green if you click it) if this response solves your problem.